# google drive search name vs fullText on google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have two files: file_sheet and file_sheet_old.

If I do the next search query:

```
fullText contains 'file_sheet_old'
```

I got the second file.

If I do the next search query:

```
fullText contains 'file_sheet'
```

I got both files, but i only want to get the first one.

I tried with

```
name contains 'file_sheet'
```

and

```
name = 'file_sheet'
```

but I got an error:

```
Invalid argument: q
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

Change query to `title = 'file_sheet'`.

#### Explanation

[Google Drive Search API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files) documentation mentions name of the file as parameter **`name`**, but [Google Apps Script's documentation on `searchQuery`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#searchfilesparams) mentions name of the file as parameter **`title`** instead.

It's a Drive bug to be aware of.